# Python: Adding boolean Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I have three lists as such:

```
a = np.array([True, True, False, False])
b = np.array([False, False, False, False])
c = np.array([False, False, False, True])
```

I want to add the arrays so that the new array only has `False` if all the corresponding elements are `False`. For example, the output should be:

```
d = np.array([True, True, False, True])
```

However, `d = np.add(a,b,c)` returns:

```
d = np.array([True, True, False, False])
```

Why is this and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
>>> a=[True, True, False, False]
>>> b=[False, False, False, False]
>>> c=[False, False, False, True]
>>> map(sum, zip(a,b,c))
[1, 1, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: This works best for me since I can pass a variable number of arrays to add up. I.e. `map(bool,map(sum, zip(*X)))` where `X = [a,b,c,...]`. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeFlip: This is using lists instead of numpy arrays. Performance will tank, the broadcasting semantics will vanish, and slices won't work right. `np.any` is a better choice.

Answer (score 13):

`np.add`'s third parameter is an optional array to put the output into. The function can only add two arrays.

Just use the normal operators (and perhaps switch to bitwise logic operators, since you're trying to do boolean logic rather than addition):

```
d = a | b | c
```

If you want a variable number of inputs, you can use the `any` function:

```
d = np.any(inputs, axis=0)
```

Comment: Adding boolean arrays does not produce integer arrays, you need to cast manually for that.

Comment: What the... huh. You're right. I could've sworn it did. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I am personally using the `np.logical_and` function.

For the problem proposed:

```
In [3]: a = np.array([True, True, False, False])
   ...: b = np.array([False, False, False, False])
   ...: c = np.array([False, False, False, True])

In [4]: np.logical_and(a,b,c)
Out[4]: array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also the straightforward solution

```
a + b + c
```

resulting in

```
array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```